# Warning: Illegal string offset when using foreach

Tags: php, sql, arrays, string, function

In my application I'm trying to print out information with a foreach. The SQL is written correctly. When I do a `var_dump` of my function I get the correct information with:

```
$eventgroupinfo = $event->GetEventGroupInfoByEventGroupId($event_group_id);
var_dump($eventgroupinfo);
```

When I try to print it out it is giving this error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset

But I get the information when I `var_dump` it. What am I doing wrong?

#### FOREACH

```
foreach ($eventgroupinfo as $g) {
  echo $g['user_id'] . $g['avatar'];
}
```

#### FUNCTION:

```
public function GetEventGroupInfoByEventGroupId($event_group_id)
{
    $db = new Db();

    $select = "SELECT
        p.event_progress_id,
        p.user_id,
        p.event_progress_distance,
        p.event_progress_date,
        p.event_group_id,
        u.user_id,
        u.name,
        u.surname,
        u.avatar
    FROM tblevent_progress p INNER JOIN tblusers u ON p.user_id = u.user_id  
    WHERE p.event_group_id = " . $event_group_id ;

    var_dump($select);
    $result = $db->conn->query($select);
    return $data=$result->fetch_assoc();
    }
}
```

#### VAR_DUMP RESULTS

```
array (size=8)
'event_progress_id' => string '1' (length=1)
'user_id' => string '1' (length=1)
'event_progress_distance' => string '2532' (length=4)
'event_progress_date' => string '2014-05-10 12:48:27' (length=19)
'event_group_id' => string '50' (length=2)
'name' => string 'Vandenbergh' (length=11)
'surname' => string 'Jan' (length=3)
'avatar' => string '139404100.jpg' (length=21)
```

Comment: Show us the `var_dump` results, otherwise we don't know the structure of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just:

```
echo   $eventgroupinfo['user_id'] . $eventgroupinfo['avatar'];
```

Instead of

```
foreach ($eventgroupinfo as $g) {
   echo   $g['user_id'] . $g['avatar'];
}
```

***P.S. :*** As `$eventgroupinfo` is a one-dimensional array  you are iterating through it like:

```
'event_progress_id'->'user_id'->...->'avatar'
```

So you `$g` is of `string` type not `array` so should not access it like `$g['user_id']`, just `$g`.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop is going to execute one time for each element in your array. In your case, you will have an iteration for each of these:

```
'event_progress_id'
'user_id'
'event_progress_distance'
'event_progress_date'
'event_group_id'
'name'
'surname'
'avatar'
```

If you are expecting multiple result sets (which it looks like you would), you'll need to return a multi-level array from your function call:

```
public function GetEventGroupInfoByEventGroupId($event_group_id)
    {
        $db = new Db();

                $select = "SELECT

                            p.event_progress_id,
                            p.user_id,
                            p.event_progress_distance,
                            p.event_progress_date,
                            p.event_group_id,
                            u.user_id,
                            u.name,
                            u.surname,
                            u.avatar


                        FROM tblevent_progress p INNER JOIN tblusers u ON p.user_id = u.user_id  
                        WHERE p.event_group_id = " . $event_group_id ;

        var_dump($select);
        $result = $db->conn->query($select);
        $entries = array();            
        while($data=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $entries[] = $data;
        }
        return $entries;
    }
```

Then your loop should output one instance for each entry in the database.